# Jython Mule ArrayList Serializing

Tags: python, mule, jython

I am using the Python Component to return an array list of employee objects
I am getting the following error message. I am able to get back results from db and the issue seems to be in the employees array list serializing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.python.core.PyType["base"]->org.python.core.PyNone["type"]->

Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.python.core.PyType["base"]->org.python.core.PyNone["type"]->org.python.core.PyType["base"]->org.python.core.PyType["base"]->org.python.core.PyType["base"]->org.python.core.PyNone[...********************************************************************************
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

```
employees = ArrayList()
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, empid, username):
        self.empid = empid
        self.username = username



Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("", "", "")
statement = connection.createStatement()
resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from xyz" + " where USER_EMPLOYEE_ID = '" + payload + "'");
while resultSet.next():
    print "%s (%s)" % (resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2))
    emp = Employee(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2))
    System.out.println(" Employee Details " + emp.empid)
    employees.add(emp)
print type(employees)   
result = employees
```

Comment: OOC why connecting to the DB from withing a Python script instead of doing it at Mule level? It's usually a bad practice to bury in code what Mule can do at config level.

Comment: David just an experiment how to use a Python component to return a collection

Comment: Roger that, thanks for the precision :)